# How to check Amazon cloudfront/S3 changelogs?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Can I see any kind of changelogs?
And is it also possible to see the IP addresses (with or without the access tokens) that were used?

Comment: Changelogs for what?

Comment: It is cloudfront, so files of course!!!

Comment: Do you mean access logs, i.e. download requests, or modifications to the objects stored in S3?

Comment: Logs of changes/modifications of the objects stores in s3!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like S3's [Server Access Logging](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) includes modification requests. You can't select what to log though, so you'd need to log all access (including anonymous downloads) and then filter the logs. Objects can't be modified via CloudFront, so you don't need to worry about that.